# image not read by java

Tags: java, image, swing

I need to read the following without change in original file. i tried like this but it throws not like an error but image is not read by the system

```
sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported color conversion request
        at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.readImage(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:136)
        at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

I tried the following code

```
  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package imagereader;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
//public class Main {
//
//    /**
//     * @param args the command line arguments
//     */
//    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        // TODO code application logic here
//    }
//
//}



    public class ColorApp extends JFrame {
    DisplayPanel displayPanel;

    JButton brightenButton, darkenButton, contrastIncButton, contrastDecButton, reverseButton, resetButton;

    public ColorApp() {
        super();
        Container container = getContentPane();

        displayPanel = new DisplayPanel();
        container.add(displayPanel);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Click a Button to Perform the Associated Operation and Reset..."));

        brightenButton = new JButton("Brightness >>");
        brightenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        darkenButton = new JButton("Darkness >>");
        darkenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        contrastIncButton = new JButton("Contrast >>");
        contrastIncButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        contrastDecButton = new JButton("Contrast <<");
        contrastDecButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        reverseButton = new JButton("Negative");
        reverseButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        panel.add(brightenButton);
        panel.add(darkenButton);
        panel.add(contrastIncButton);
        panel.add(contrastDecButton);
        panel.add(reverseButton);
        panel.add(resetButton);

        container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);

        addWindowListener(new WindowEventHandler());
        setSize(displayPanel.getWidth(), displayPanel.getHeight() + 25);
        show();
    }

    class WindowEventHandler extends WindowAdapter {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new ColorApp();
   }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

            if (button.equals(brightenButton)) {
                displayPanel.brightenLUT();
                displayPanel.applyFilter();
                displayPanel.repaint();
            } else if (button.equals(darkenButton)) {
                displayPanel.darkenLUT();
                displayPanel.applyFilter();
                displayPanel.repaint();
            } else if (button.equals(contrastIncButton)) {
                displayPanel.contrastIncLUT();
                displayPanel.applyFilter();
                displayPanel.repaint();
            } else if (button.equals(contrastDecButton)) {
                displayPanel.contrastDecLUT();
                displayPanel.applyFilter();
                displayPanel.repaint();
            } else if (button.equals(reverseButton)) {
                displayPanel.reverseLUT();
                displayPanel.applyFilter();
                displayPanel.repaint();
            } else if (button.equals(resetButton)) {
                displayPanel.reset();
                displayPanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}

    class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {
    Image displayImage;

    BufferedImage bi;

    Graphics2D big;

    LookupTable lookupTable;

    DisplayPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.black); // panel background color
        loadImage();
        setSize(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getWidth(this)); // panel
        createBufferedImage();
    }

    public void loadImage() {
        displayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:/Documents and Settings/admin/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/Imagereader/src/imagereader/ne-1.jpg");
        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
        mt.addImage(displayImage, 1);
        try {
            mt.waitForAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while loading.");
        }

        if (displayImage.getWidth(this) == -1) {
            System.out.println("No jpg file");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void createBufferedImage() {
        bi = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        big = bi.createGraphics();
        big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void brightenLUT() {
        short brighten[] = new short[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            short pixelValue = (short) (i + 10);
            if (pixelValue > 255)
                pixelValue = 255;
            else if (pixelValue < 0)
                pixelValue = 0;
            brighten[i] = pixelValue;
        }
        lookupTable = new ShortLookupTable(0, brighten);
    }

    public void darkenLUT() {
        short brighten[] = new short[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            short pixelValue = (short) (i - 10);
            if (pixelValue > 255)
                pixelValue = 255;
            else if (pixelValue < 0)
                pixelValue = 0;
            brighten[i] = pixelValue;
        }
        lookupTable = new ShortLookupTable(0, brighten);
    }

    public void contrastIncLUT() {
        short brighten[] = new short[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            short pixelValue = (short) (i * 1.2);
            if (pixelValue > 255)
                pixelValue = 255;
            else if (pixelValue < 0)
                pixelValue = 0;
            brighten[i] = pixelValue;
        }
        lookupTable = new ShortLookupTable(0, brighten);
    }

    public void contrastDecLUT() {
        short brighten[] = new short[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            short pixelValue = (short) (i / 1.2);
            if (pixelValue > 255)
                pixelValue = 255;
            else if (pixelValue < 0)
                pixelValue = 0;
            brighten[i] = pixelValue;
        }
        lookupTable = new ShortLookupTable(0, brighten);
    }

    public void reverseLUT() {
        byte reverse[] = new byte[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            reverse[i] = (byte) (255 - i);
        }
        lookupTable = new ByteLookupTable(0, reverse);
    }

    public void reset() {
        big.setColor(Color.black);
        big.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this));
        big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void applyFilter() {
        LookupOp lop = new LookupOp(lookupTable, null);
        lop.filter(bi, bi);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        paintComponent(g);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
    }
   }
```

Comment: How big is this JPEG (in bytes).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can't you(he) just read image by `BufferedImage` class or `ImageIO`?

Comment: @Yoda if you mean *"..by `BufferedImage` class **using** `ImageIO`?"* then ..possibly.  A lot of images that cannot be read one way, cannot be read another.

Comment: Does this happen with all JPEGs, or just one (or a few) in particular?   If so, attach or link such a JPEG. Switching to `ImageIO` sounds like a good idea, as it gives more flexibility (plugin-based) and is more predictable when things go wrong... If that doesn't help, you could try using my [`JPEGImageReader` plugin for ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg), it will read most JPEGs the built-in reader won't read.

Answer (score 3):

I think your images are in adobe cmyk or cmyk  so only the system not able to read the images.
You can try using image magick tool to convert cmyk to rgb. This tool can rin command from terminal mode. So please use this it will solve your problem

Terminal Command:

For single image use this:
convert original.png -colorspace RGB ouput.jpg

For batch of images use this:
folder path> mogrify -colorspace RGB *.jpg

Comment: Add `-synchronize flag` to imagemagick commands to always flush to the file.